# PHP Decompress .tar.gz with archive_tar

Tags: php, tar

I want to decompress and extract a **.tar.gz** file. My webhost refuses to update it's PHP, and therefore I cannot use '`PharData`' functions. I have the following code for `.tar` files:

```
try {
      $tar = new Archive_Tar('autoinstaller_archive.tar');
      $tar->extract(dirname(__FILE__) . $_POST['exto']);
      echo 'DONE EXTRACTING!<br/>';
      $ok = true;
    } 
catch (Exception $e) 
    {
      echo 'Something bad happened!!';
    }
```

How can I decompress it to a `.tar` WITHOUT USING:

```
 $p = new PharData('autoinstaller_archive.tar.gz');
    $p->decompress();
```

Comment: If your hosts allows it you can simply run a `system('gunzip ' . $file);` call to gunzip the file at it's current location.

Comment: Doesn't Archive_Tar have gzip support if PHP has the zlib extension loaded?

Comment: You also have things like [gzopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php) from PHP >4.

Comment: thanks. wish I could upvote your comments!